# DM user by ID c#

Tags: c#, discord.net

I want to DM a user by ID using c#, Here's what I've tried

```
        var u = "user-id";
        string msg = "your message";
        await UserExtensions.SendMessageAsync(u, msg);
```

It returns with:

```
cannot convert from 'string' to 'Discord.IUser'
```

I've searched and I couldn't find away to turn a string to Discord.IUser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the user as IUser, to get the user as IUser you can use _client.GetUserAsync('UserID'):

```c
ulong u = 0; // Insert the user ID here
string msg = "your message";

// Get the user with the ID from your DiscordSocketClient
var user = _client.GetUserAsync(u).Result;

await UserExtensions.SendMessageAsync(user, msg);
```

Comment: I had to replace _client.GetUserAsync(u) with _client.GetUser(u);

Comment: I'm using SocketClient

Comment: Hm, does it work?

Comment: Well no, What Client do you use?

Comment: is it DiscordSocketRestClient, I'm having trouble importing it

Comment: Im using the DiscordSocketClient https://discordnet.dev/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.html
This is the client which you create when starting your bot... this should be one of the first things which happens when starting the bot.

Comment: How I declared it: _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

Comment: How'd you declare it?

Comment: using var services = ConfigureServices();
var client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>()

Comment: is this seperate? using var services = ConfigureServices();

Comment: In which case are you using this code? In a slashcommand or as part of a button click event?

Comment: ConfigureServices highlights with The name 'ConfigureServices' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Im using it as a prefix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241963/discussion-between-hovernot-and-bobsty).

Comment: Yes, lets start from the beginning. 
The DiscordSocketClient is usually declared in the Program.cs file. You can either pass the client as a parameter through to your handeling class or you can in some cases use `Context.Client`. 
So in which case are you using this code?

Comment: Maybe try using the command context.Client

Comment: no, i use message.content, ill just declare it as a seperate like _client2

Comment: That does not make sense. Your client is your Bot .. you would be trying to make a second instance of you bot which wont work.

Comment: Now thinking about that, it won't work.

Comment: But how can I fix the ConfigureServices thing?

Comment: Do you have a Program.cs file in your bot? Or which file is your entry file?

Comment: Entry file................................

Comment: Okay, go to your bot, stop debugging and Press F10 ... the file which is shown is your entry file. In this file you should see the client being declared. You should be able to pass this client through to your handler class as parameter. From there on you can use the client to get the user.

Comment: I'm still new at coding, can you explain it more simply?

Comment: Can you add me on Discord so I can maybe show you this on a screenshare?

Comment: Whats your user?

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.Message.Author.Id);
await user.SendMessageAsync("This is my message!");
```